# How to automate job running after another job succesfully completed?

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

Suppose i have two multi-branch pipeline jenkins job ABC and XYZ, now i want to start XYZ job automatically while ABC job completed successfully. How can i do it ?

Comment: Hi @Niladri Dey if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jenkins pipeline

```
node(){
  ..
  .. 
  ..
  if (currentBuild.result == "SUCCESS") {
    // If wait is set to true you can use the downstream_build.result to define the 
    //currentBuild.result
    def downstream_build = build job: '<path-to>/another-build-job', wait: true
    // Here you can set dependency between downstream and current build job
    currentBuild.result = downstream_build.result
  }
}
```

If you set `wait` to `false` your pipeline can immediately finish but you can't use the downstream_build.result

```
node(){
  ..
  .. 
  ..
  if (currentBuild.result == "SUCCESS") {
    def downstream_build = build job: '<path-to>/another-build-job', wait: false
  }
}
```

Another way is the [Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)